# Fake a dual monitor

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors

So I want to have two monitors on a single monitor setup, so that I can work with TeamViewer ie. While using the main monitor for other stuff in the background.

So no virtual desktops, please! That's not a "display"! And won't give me what I need.

I saw the other thread, tried them all except installing "TightVNC", as I don't want a VNC server running.

With the windows 10, the extended display does nothing(sets itself back to "PC Screen only" when the menu closes). There's no "screen resolution" option and detect monitors doesn't work. Setting resolution to the double obviously doesn't work(as it tries to fit all on one display, not two). iDisplay only works when it has a connection to a phone or tablet.

How can I emulate a second screen WITHOUT actually plugging in a second display? Or if there is a teeny tiny display DisplayPort/HDMI gadget to make it fake, that's fine.

Comment: "I saw the other thread" What other thread? We are not mind readers.

Comment: If your monitor has both VGA and another method of connecting, get your monitor connected by both cables. This should allow Windows to see 2 monitors even if it is the same monitor.

Comment: I actually have this PC connected to two monitors, the other monitor is used by another PC. And I still only have 1 montior on this. But I might see a solution down the road here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I heard about those dummy plugs to emulate a display connection, but I never tested one.

You can buy those on Amazon for various interfaces like HDMI, DVI, VGA ...

Comment: I found one - search terms include: "Virtual Display DP Displayport Dummy Plug Headless Ghost Emulator Adapter".  You can also search for "Display Port EDID Emulator", in a past place of employment we used those to allow people to remote into a powerful desktop for AutoCAD use with no physical displays attached - the HP remote desktop software and/or graphics card insisted on checking video ports for EDID info before allowing remote access to a display.